# "formed" in "This train is formed of four carriages"

Tags: meaning

Scotrail platform announcements use the phrase, "formed of four carriages".  "formed", appears excessive compared to say, "this train has four carriages."

Example audio:

- 3 carriages: https://youtu.be/VtzW4oFSCaw?t=20
- 4 carriages: https://youtu.be/VtzW4oFSCaw?t=103
- 6 carriages: https://youtu.be/VtzW4oFSCaw?t=59

Can someone explain why such usage, when brevity should be more important?

Comment: I don't hear a clear 'all' - it may just be the effect of inserting the number into the recorded message.

Comment: A combination of Scots accent and announcement quality, another example in the clip makes it obvious that it is "formed of x carriages".  https://youtu.be/VtzW4oFSCaw?t=59. thanks

Comment: I'm not hearing "all", even allowing for the fact that in Scots "all" is often contracted to ["a'"](https://dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/a_adj_adv) or similar. "Formed" might be railway jargon, or because it's clearer and less ambiguous to use extra words and say "This train is formed of four carriages" than saying "This train is four carriages".

Comment: 'Can someone explain why such usage, when brevity might be considered the controlling factor?' avoids begging the question. And is your quote exact? 'A train formed of four carriages ...' sounds more natural than 'a service formed of four carriages.' Quotes should be stripped out on ELU, not left for contributors to search for.

Comment: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Diesel_Locomotives_Around_the_World/FwqtEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22train+is+formed+of+four%22&pg=PA1942&printsec=frontcover

Comment: I'd probably use "consists of".

Comment: The original question seemed to be focused on *all*. In the current version *all* does not appear at all; the focus now seems to be on the choice of *formed* rather than, say, *has*. This has changed the question significantly, and made the answer, which was responding to the original version, seem out of place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Platforms, especially at a terminus, can be occupied by a long train of multiple carriages which might be split before departing. This can happen when a long, busy train (say an inbound rush hour service) arrives at a platform and then is split into smaller trains for outbound destinations.

Therefore, it's possible to hear an announcement that a service is "formed of the front four carriages at platform X", which means only those four carriages will depart. The remaining carriages will sit at the platform to form a different train. In the case of "formed of all four carriages", it would mean that only four carriages were on a given platform and all of them would form the departing service.

This style of announcement intended to prevent passengers joining carriages that won't be part of the departing service.

Comment: I have recently just entered a carriage not part of the departing train too, qed.

Comment: And sometimes the train divides in two at a certain point, to serve different branch lines, so you have to make sure you are in the right half for where you want to go!

Comment: (Disclaimer: lifelong railway enthusiast) In the old days, trains consisted of a set of carriages called a 'rake' by railway people, hauled by a 'locomotive'. The rake would be 'formed' (by 'coupling' the carriages). Carriages could be removed or added en-route. These days most trains are 'fixed-formation' types (multiple units and what lay folk sometimes call 'bullet trains') UK railway people are famously conservative in their terminology.

Comment: https://www.google.com/books/edition/Knife_Edge/T0c6AgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22train+is+formed+of+four%22&pg=PT47&printsec=frontcover

Answer (score 0):

Although the phrase jars a bit and you could exchange 'formed' with 'comprised', 'formed' may well be railway protocol language... and
.. 'comprised' may not be as common in usage as formed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).